# async function in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a service which returns a function but the function doesn't return a value. Here is the code:

```
function getUser() {
    var Users = $resource('/api/users',{},{query: {method: 'get', isArray: true}});
    return Users.query({username:localStorage.getItem("token")}).$promise
}

function userrole() {
    var userrole='';

    var tmp=getUser();
    tmp.then(function(user){
        var userrole= user[0].role;
        console.log('The role is '+user[0].role);
        userrole=user[0].role;
        return userrole;
    });
    console.log('@ the end of userrole');
}
```

The function which doesn't return is `userrole`. I believe it's because of an async problem. How can I go about solving this?

Comment: What do you see in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use async methods in AngularJS (and in all Javascript) you need to use it always in functions above.

For example:

```
function getUser() {
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  var Users = $resource('/api/users', {}, {
    query: {method: 'get', isArray: true}
  });


  return Users.query({username: token}).$promise;
}

function getUserRole() {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    getUser()
      .then(function(user){
        resolve(user[0].role);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
}

getUserRole().then(function (userRole) {
  console.log('The role is ' + userRole);
});
```

Comment: [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is simple analog of Promise in AngularJS

Comment: getUser apparently already returns a promise, why construct another?

Comment: @danh. getUser returns user data. getUserRole handles the user response and returns the role of the user. We can add any handler in getUserRole and use it.

Comment: @Danil valov 10x.  I will upvote ur answer and accept it

Comment: I don't see any reason to wrap the function that already returns the promise to  return another one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but just return 
`return tmp.then(...` then when you will be able to call `userrole().then((role) => ... )` from other place. Besides of that fix your indentations.

Comment: What this answer means (correctly) is that the async function can't return the user role, it can/should return a promise to get the user role.

Comment: @danh 10x and how on earth can i manipulate data from a query

Comment: @julianaMorales  What do you mean by manipulating data from the query? If the promise succeeds(like request) then when you can call `.then((dataReturnedFromPromise) => `. That's it, and if you chain `.then` callbacks then the next `then` function will return whatever you returned in the previous `.then` callback.